# How to get total records with pagination in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-7

In my `product` index I have 60K records, I'm running a match query with *from*, *size* params. by default, ES support a 10k record search so I have increased it to 60k.

My issue is I'm already passing **size** param from API & I want to search in 60K records with the same pagination size param.

**So how I can match 60k records with my pagination size param.**

Here is my code:

```
const query = {
    query: {
        match: {
            name: {
                query: req.text
            }
        }
    }
}

const { body: { hits } } = await esclient.search({
    from: req.skip || 0,
    size: req.offset || 50,
    index: productsIndex,
    type: productsType,
    body: query,
});
```

here code with 60K size:

```
const query = {
    query: {
        match: {
            name: {
                query: req.text
            }
        }
    },
    size:60000
}
```

in my query, if I use size=60K, I'm getting 20 records (without that I'm getting 12 records) but I can't use pagination params.

Comment: Do you have any errors when you do the search? As I see, you have already aware of `index.max_result_window` setting. Could you give more detail to understand the real problem here? Do you want to see the number of matched products?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly,

**size** parameter is the number of hits/documents you want in response. It's not that elasticsearch will process your query only in first **size** number of documents. 10K is the maximum number of documents you can get in response. If you specify **size** more than 10K, elastic search will give you an error like this.
[ES error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7Ftc.png)

Without worring about the above problem, use **from** and **size** as the parameters for your pagination.

Comment: you can modify limit using `"max_result_window": 60000`, that's my issue if use **size** 60k getting 20 records, otherwise 12.